# Solidity Error :: ParserError: Expected '(' but got 'public'

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, ether

I keep getting this error.......

```
"from solidity:
ParserError: Expected '(' but got 'public'
 --> contracts/3_Ballot.sol:6:24:
  |
6 |     function PiggyBank public()
  |                        ^^^^^^",
```

what to do?

```
    pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
    contract PiggyBank{
    address creator;
    uint deposits;

    function PiggyBank public()          \\error in this line
    {
        creator=msg.sendor;
        deposits=0;
    }

    function deposit() payable returns(uint)
    {
        if(msg.value>0)
        deposits=deposits+1;
        return getNumberofDeposits();  
    }

    function getNumberofDeposits() constant returns(uint)
    {
        return deposit;
    }
    
    function Killl();{
    if(msg.sendor==creator)
    selfdestruct(creator);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using syntax from older solidity versions, which is not supported in the current 0.8 version.

First, to get rid of the syntax error, replace `function PiggyBank public()` to `function PiggyBank() public`.

In older versions of Solidity (up to 0.5), a function with the same name as the contract was used as a constructor. In the current version 0.8, you need to use the `constructor` keyword - otherwise the function would be publicly invokable by anyone and anytime (not just during the contract deployment).

```
// replace `function PiggyBank public()` to `constructor()`
constructor() {
    creator=msg.sendor;
    deposits=0;
}
```

Then few more syntax errors (incorrectly defined functions; an extra semicolon at the `Killl()` function definition; missing visibility modifiers), a type error (`selfdestruct` argument needs to be `payable`), and typos (your code uses `msg.sendor` instead of `msg.sender`) show up. See the corrected code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract PiggyBank {
    address creator;
    uint deposits;

    constructor() {
        creator=msg.sender;
        deposits=0;
    }

    function deposit() public payable returns(uint) {
        if(msg.value>0) {
            deposits=deposits+1;
        }
        return getNumberofDeposits();  
    }

    function getNumberofDeposits() public view returns(uint) {
        return deposits;
    }
    
    function Killl() public {
        if(msg.sender==creator) {
            selfdestruct(payable(creator));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've used the code which you have corrected but again getting error here, 

 creator=msg.sendor;

//TypeError: Member "sendor" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in msg.

&

function deposit() payable returns(uint)

//SyntaxError: No visibility specified. Did you intend to add "public"?


&

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
//Warning: SPDX license identifier not provided in source file. Before publishing, consider adding a comment containing "SPDX-License-Ide

Comment: @Chahat The correct form is `msg.sender`, not `msg.sendor`... You need to specify visibility of each function, see the corrected code... The warning is just about missing license identifier, the warning message literally gives you a recommendation how to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for help. The code is working fine now. I just didn't looked at the spelling of sender earlier but yeah it's all good now.